# Animating to another background-color, then back again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make my white background flash green. Currently I have this code which turns it green:

```
$( "#modal_newmessage" ).animate({
    backgroundColor: "#8bed7e"
}, 500 );
```

However, I can't figure how to make it turn white again in the same animation. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chain another `.animate()` call since the animations will be queued in the `fx` queue.

```
$("#modal_newmessage").animate({
  backgroundColor: "#8bed7e"
}, 500).animate({
  backgroundColor: "#fff"
}, 500);
```

Remember most jQuery functions are chainable without need to call `$("#modal_newmessage")` twice.

[See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/7BLZw/)

Comment: If you don't want to have to specify the original color (I know the OP did, but it might be useful to someone else) another option might be to include jquery ui which allows you to animate addClass. You could animate a class that applies a green background and then animate removeClass to return it to the original.

Comment: @wetjosh, indeed, but this is not a jQuery UI question. We keep it simple around here when there's no need to add so much overhead to a simple task ;)

Comment: @wetjosh, that's true! But how can you achieve it? Putting `className += " highlighted";` inside the `.animate({...})` block gave me nothing...

Comment: @AlMacks with jQuery UI you need not use the animate function. Use the addClass function instead and simply add a duration. See my code pen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYZQLe and see the docs here: https://jqueryui.com/addClass/

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$( "#modal_newmessage" ).animate({
    backgroundColor: "#8bed7e"
}, 500, function() {
    $( "#modal_newmessage" ).animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff" });
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {

    $( "#modal_newmessage" ).animate({
      backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
      color: "#fff",
      width: 500
    }, 1000 ).animate({
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
      color: "#000",
      width: 240
    }, 1000 );
});
```

## note:

For animating background colors you need `jQuery ui` for color animation.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is not animating back and forth in a single animation, this requires clicks to go back

Comment: yes that is done on click if you want it on `doc ready` then this needs some mods.